# How to specify href as object in vuetify

Tags: vue.js, routes, vuetify.js

I want to create a button that redirects to `/forgot-password?rol=XXXX` on vuetify. Currently I'm doing this manually but [vuetify docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-btn/#props-href) especify it can be done with an object. But I didn't find anything specifying what kind of object or requirements it must have.

How can I pass the arguments as an object? Is that object a [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL)?

```
<v-btn
    class="secondary--text"
    x-small
    plain
    v-t="'components.login.forgot_password'"
    :href="`/forgot-password?rol=${rol}`"
>
</v-btn>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add the path as an object, you need to specify the `path` and `query` properties.

In you, case will be something like that.

```
{ path: '/forgot-password', query: { rol: rol }}
```

For more resources.

https://router.vuejs.org/api/#to